# Showing equivalence of coefficients in a linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following system:

$$
y_1 = (G_{11} H_{11} + G_{12} H_{21}) x_1 + (G_{11} H_{12} + G_{12} H_{22}) x_2 \qquad \mathrm{(1)} \\
y_2 = (G_{22} H_{21} + G_{21} H_{11}) x_1 + (G_{22} H_{22} + G_{21} H_{12}) x_2 \qquad \mathrm{(2)}
$$

I know this system is approximately diagonal, hence:

$$
G_{11} H_{11} + G_{12} H_{21} = G_{22} H_{22} + G_{21} H_{12} \approx 1 \qquad \mathrm{(3)} \\
G_{11} H_{12} + G_{12} H_{22} = G_{22} H_{21} + G_{21} H_{11} \approx 0 \qquad \mathrm{(4)}
$$

Numerically, I know that also

$$
G_{21} H_{22} + G_{11} H_{21} \approx 1 \qquad \mathrm{(5)}\\
G_{22} H_{22} + G_{12} H_{21} \approx 0 \qquad \mathrm{(6)}
$$

I fail to show the equivalence. It should be trivial to show by just plugging (3,4) into (5,6). I tried all substituting all possible combinations e.g. into (6) but the result is always nonzero. The problem is that (3-4) contain all 16 possible permutations and none of (3-4) contains just two permutations of (5) or (6).

I guess I am missing something trivial ...

Answer (score 1):

(1) and (2) can be written in matrix/vector form as

$$
y = G H x
$$

where $H_{ij}$ and $G_{ij}$ are the elements of the $G$ and $H$ matrix.

The conditions (3-4) imply

$$
G H \approx I
$$

This implies that $G \approx H^{-1}$ and hence

$$
H G \approx I
$$

Expanding $H G$ it can be seen that (5-6) are the elements of this matrix which must be 1 for the diagonal (5) and zero for the off-diagonal (6).